# C# Tasks - Asynchronously Get Value from UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I have a method within a C# class I am trying to call on a separate thread. However, I need to  have this function access multiple values from the user interface BEFORE it begins processing, like this:

```
public void validateConnections(bool openExpanderOnError = true) {
//Gather information about the data connection models, and which rows to test
    string connectorValue = DBTypes[connector.SelectedValue.ToString()];
    EntryRow[] testable = { developer, production, qaTesting, ... , more };

//Run long code
    //Churn.....
}
```

The variables I have in the above code are defined by getting values which reside within the same class, and this works fine if it is executed synchronously.

However, in order to run the long code below (which I clipped for brevity), these values need to be present BEFOREHAND. It is not practical to pass all of the information that I need as parameters, as that will get unruly very quickly.

How can I get these values from the UI asynchronously?

**Note:** I tried using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` for this portion of the code, and that caused the long code to run before the required variables had been set. Using a `BackgroundWorker` caused the main thread to freeze while the long code was running, completely defeating the purpose of the second thread.

**Edit 1:** Here is how I tried to implement the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` method call:

```
public void validateConnections(bool openExpanderOnError = true) {
//Gather information about the data connection models, and which rows to test
    string connectorValue = "";
    EntryRow[] testable = new EntryRow[n];

    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
        connectorValue = DBTypes[connector.SelectedValue.ToString()];
        testable[0] = developer;
        testable[1] = production;
        //...
        testable[n] = qaTesting;
    }));

//Run long code
    //Churn.....
}
```

**Edit 2:** It was `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` that I had originally called, not `Dispatcher.Invoke()`, which works properly.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke is the solution, show us how you tried using it.

Comment: @RobertLevy I have edited my question, as requested.

Comment: That code looks correct.  Dispatcher.Invoke is synchronous so the long code won't begin until the dispatched  method completes.  Perhaps you accidentally used Dispatcher.BeginInvoke before?  That's the async version which would have the behavior you described

Comment: @RobertLevy Ah... that's possible. Sorry for asking such a silly question. |-( It appears to work properly now. Thank you, Robert! If you add you comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Dispatcher.Invoke is synchronous so the long code won't begin until the dispatched method completes. Perhaps you accidentally used Dispatcher.BeginInvoke before? That's the async version which would have the behavior you described